# behat Selenium2Driver "could not open connection"

Tags: symfony, selenium-webdriver, behat, mink

i'm am trying tu use Behat + Mink + Selenium2Driver into Symfony2.

- i ran Selenium Server.
- my behat.yml is:

```
    default:  
        extensions:  
            Behat\Symfony2Extension\Extension:  
                mink_driver: true  
            Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:  
                default_session: 'symfony2'  
                base_url: http://localhost/fhm_mind_solution/app_dev.php/  
                selenium2:  
                    wd_host: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub'  
                    capabilities: { "browser": "firefox", "version": "23"}
```

- in my FeatureContext.php:

```
    class FeatureContext extends RawMinkContext  
                      implements KernelAwareInterface
    {
        private $kernel;
        private $parameters; 
        public function __construct(array $parameters)
        {
            $this->useContext('mink', new MinkContext);
        }     
    /* [...] */
          public function iCanAuthenticateAsAnAdmin()
      {
            $this->getSession();
      }
```

- when i lauch Behat, i have always this: "could not open connection". What is missing?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you didn't configure selenium driver properly. It should be:

```
default:  
    extensions:  
        Behat\Symfony2Extension\Extension:  
            mink_driver: true  
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:  
            default_session: 'symfony2'  
            base_url: http://localhost/fhm_mind_solution/app_dev.php/  
            selenium2:  
                wd_host: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub'  
                capabilities: { "browser": "firefox", "version": "23"}
```

Secondly, you don't have to initialize the driver nor the session yourself. It's done for you by the MinkExtension.

Simply make that your context extends the `Behat\MinkExtension\Context\RawMinkContext` and you'll get access to the `$this->getSession()` method.

Read more in the official docs: http://extensions.behat.org/mink/

You can see available capabilities in the selenium2 configuration: https://github.com/Behat/MinkExtension/blob/2.0/src/Behat/MinkExtension/services/sessions/selenium2.xml#L10

Comment: hi,

on the first point: i already tryed that cnfiguration for behat.yml, but i have this error:    [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]

  Unrecognized options "wd_capabilities" under "behat.extensions.behat_minkexten
sion_extension.selenium2"  On the second point, can you give an example for the class definition?

Comment: That's because the parameter is called "capabilities". On the second point, read the friendly manual please (I've pasted the link to the docs where you can find it).

Comment: One more thing - you need to install the selenium2 driver: https://packagist.org/packages/behat/mink-selenium2-driver

Comment: is it this one: "behat/mink-selenium2-driver":  "*@stable" in composer.json? then, it is installed.

Comment: i found out that the exception is catched here: https://github.com/Behat/MinkSelenium2Driver/blob/master/src/Behat/Mink/Driver/Selenium2Driver.php, at line 278. does it help? i don't know what to do...

Comment: Is your selenium server running on the same machine you're running behat?

Comment: yes, it's the same machine, but i'm running it on Windows. today i will try on my Linux machine and i tell you then.